# Add 'Changed' Event for each Radio Btn

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add Eventhandlers to RadioButtons, that are placed inside a jQuery DataTable. I can do this by adding it with the 'live' function like this:

```
$("input[name='Button0']").live("change", function() {
    radioValue[0] = $(this).val();
});
```

The button names are generated dynamically for each DataTable Row. I have a List of questions and for every question there is a radio button group. I have tried something like this:

```
var countRows = 0;
$.each(questionList, function (index, value) {
    var btnName = 'Button' + countRows.toString();
    $("input[name="+btnName+"]").live("change", function () {
        radioValue[countRows] = $(this).val();
    });
    countRows++;
});
```

However this gives me weird behaviour in filling my 'radioValue' array as it fills in only one value on a totally wrong index which shouldn't even exist.

This is my html:

```
    <div class="content" id="IndexCompletion">
<h2>Erfassen der Leistung für Mitarbeiter: @Model.Mitarbeiter.Vorname @Model.Mitarbeiter.Nachname</h2>

<div class="dataTableSurrounding">
    <table id="surveyTable">
        <thead>
            <th>Frage</th>
            @foreach (var answerOption in Model.Survey.Questions.FirstOrDefault().AnswerOptions)
            {
                <th>@answerOption.Description</th>
            }
        </thead>
        <tbody class="dynamicTryOut">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<div>
    <input type="button" id="saveSurvey" value="Senden">
</div>
```

And this is the script section:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    @section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var val1, val2;

    var questionList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Model.JsonStringQuestions)));
    var answerOptionList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Model.JsonStringAnswerOptions)));
    var radioValue = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#surveyTable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": false,
            "orderMulti": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": '@Url.Action("LoadSurvey", "Home")',
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [{ "data": "Text", "name": "Text", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<input type="radio" class="questionButton" name="Button' + meta.row + '" value="1">';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<input type="radio" class="questionButton" name="Button' + meta.row + '" value="2">';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<input type="radio" class="questionButton" name="Button' + meta.row + '" value="3">';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<input type="radio" class="questionButton" name="Button' + meta.row + '" value="4">';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<input type="radio" class="questionButton" name="Button' + meta.row + '" value="5">';
                    }
                }],
            "language": {
                "info": "Seite _PAGE_ von _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "Keine Einträge verfügbar",
                "lengthMenu": "_MENU_ Einträge pro Seite",
                "zeroRecords": "Keine Einträge gefunden",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)",
                "processing": "Lade Formular",
                "paginate": {
                    "next": "Weiter",
                    "previous": "Zurück"
                }
            }
        });

        $("#saveSurvey").click(function() {
            $('<form action=@Url.Action("SaveSurvey") method="POST">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="surveyId" value="' + @Model.Survey.Id + '">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="val1" value="' + val1 + '">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="val2" value="' + val2 + '">' +
                '</form>').submit();
        });

        var counters = 0;
        $.each(questionList, function (index, value) {
            $('input[name="Button' + counters + '"]').on('change', function () {
                alert("worked");
                radioValue[counters] = $(this).val();
            });
            counters++;
        });
    });
</script>
    }
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you give a working example of your code in a snippet or fiddle as it's difficult to visualise exactly what you're trying to achieve. At the very least seeing the HTML would help. All I can say for definite, though, is that you shouldn't be using `live()`. It was deprecated a *long* time ago. You should be using the delegated form of `on`. I'd suggest you should update your version of jQuery too. Also you only ever affect the element at the `0` index of the array as you never change the `countRows` value

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: Would this: ("input[name="+btnName+"]").on("change", function () { .... }); be correct syntax for .on()?

Comment: why not use `index` instead of `countRows`? Also, everyone has forgotten to say that the `.live` method was removed from jQuery as of version 1.9

Comment: I used 1.8 and `.live()` worked as expected. I am trying to use `.on()`now but can't get it to work. Because Index gives me the ID of my Object, and that is just wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the weird counting behaviour by calling a user defined function inside a for loop like this:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < questionArr.length; i++) {
            attachChangeEvent(i);
        } 


        function attachChangeEvent(index) {
            $('input[name="Button' + index + '"]').live('change', function () {
                radioValue[index] = $(this).val();
            });
        }
```

It seems that introducing a counter and using the $.each() loop creates unwanted behaviour. Splitting the counting and the adding of the event resolves this problem.

But i stil didn't manage to get `.on()`to work.

Thanks for your ideas.